# Retrieve maximum value from a table containing duplicate values according to a condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table tbl_usertests from which i want to retrieve the user who have maximum testscore for each test.

**Note: User here means usertestid which is unique.**

Its colums are:

```
    pk_usertestid   attemptdate     uploaddate  fk_tbl_tests_testid     fk_tbl_users_userid     testscore   totalquestionsnotattempted  totalquestionscorrect   totalquestionsincorrect     totalquestions  timetaken   iscurrent
```

data :

```
1;NULL;"2010-06-24 22:48:07";"11";"3";"1";"53";"1";"21";"75";"92";"1"
2;NULL;"2010-06-25 01:21:37";"11";"4";"13";"0";"13";"62";"75";"801";"1"
3;NULL;"2010-06-25 01:21:50";"10";"4";"17";"5";"17";"53";"75";"640";"1"
4;NULL;"2010-06-25 01:24:23";"11";"4";"13";"0";"13";"62";"75";"801";"1"
5;NULL;"2010-06-25 01:24:47";"10";"4";"17";"5";"17";"53";"75";"640";"1"
6;NULL;"2010-06-25 01:36:04";"11";"5";"13";"0";"13";"62";"75";"801";"1"
7;NULL;"2010-06-25 01:47:26";"7";"5";"10";"1";"10";"49";"60";"302";"1"
```

My Query is :

```
SELECT max(`testscore`) , `fk_tbl_tests_testid` , `fk_tbl_users_userid` , `pk_usertestid`
FROM `tbl_usertests`
GROUP BY `fk_tbl_tests_testid`
```

This query output:

```
max(`testscore`)    fk_tbl_tests_testid     fk_tbl_users_userid     pk_usertestid
    10                7                          5                     7
    17               10                          4                     3
    13               11                          3                     1
```

But the problem is that if there are two users who have same score, it displays only one user because i have used group by clause.

For. e.g. testid =10 i have two records(pk_usertestid 3 and 5) but it displays 3 only.

I want the user whose upload date is less than the other user(in case of two users having same testscore). It should display for usertestid=3 since 3 upload date is less than 5.
Right now its displaying 3 but it is due to group by clause.

I am unable to construct the query.

Please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  t.`fk_tbl_tests_testid` , t.`fk_tbl_users_userid` , t.`pk_usertestid`, maxscores.maxscore
FROM `tbl_usertests` t
JOIN (SELECT `fk_tbl_tests_testid`,max(`testscore`) as maxscore
    FROM `tbl_usertests`
    GROUP BY `fk_tbl_tests_testid`) maxscores ON t.`fk_tbl_tests_testid` = maxscores.`fk_tbl_tests_testid`
```

the logic behind is to separate the whole thing into two parts: get the maximum (or any other aggregate) values for each group (this is the subquery part), then for each element, join the corresponding aggregate. (JOIN it back to the riginal table)